# apply ng class on invalid return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to apply  `bootstrap has-error` class on an invalid return from a method in controller. But none of my attempts seem to be working. Here is how I am doing it:

```
<form role="form" name="configForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Not between</label>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <tr style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold">
                <td style="width: 50%">Lower Bound</td>
                <td style="width: 50%">Upper Bound</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="bounds in themeComponents.components[compKey].boundaries.notBetween">
                <td>
                    <input name="betweenLowBound" class="form-control" ng-model="bounds.lower" ng-class="{'has-error' : checkBounds(bounds.lower, bounds.upper) == true }">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="betweenUpperBound" class="form-control" ng-model="bounds.upper" ng-class="{'has-error' : checkBounds(bounds.lower, bounds.upper) == true }">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="removeEasingItem(compKey, bounds)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
                                           </i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my simple check in controller:

```
$scope.checkBounds = function (lower, upper) {
    if(lower > upper)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Also, how could I design this as an inline `ng-if` expression rather than a method in a controller? I want the `td-input` to go to `error` state when `upperbound` value is greater than `lowerbound`..

Comment: `'has-error' : bounds.lower > bounds.upper`

Comment: @tymeJV the statement does apply `has-error` to the `td-input`, however the border does not go `red` like it is supposed to..

Comment: Then it's a CSS problem with the class - not the Angular. Mess with the style in the web-inspector.

Comment: it is the default `bootstrap` invalid input class that I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-class to dynamically add the css: 
`ng-class="{ 'has-error': bounds.lower > bounds.upper}"`